# Multiple scratch buffers

Tags: scratch-buffer

Would like to use two scratch buffers on two side-by-side windows.  How can I do this thing?  Can only also ask for more than two scratch buffers that can be named?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first scratch buffer, do `C-x 4 b` (`switch-to-buffer-other-window`) and supply `second-scratch` (or whatever) as argument. In your new buffer, do `M-x lisp-interaction-mode` and that's it.

Doing this from elisp is an exercise for the reader.

The point is that there is nothing magic about a scratch buffer: it is simply a buffer with major-mode `lisp-interaction-mode`.

Comment: Would still need some help for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I whipped this up based off of the other answer.

```lisp
(defun mw::make-scratch-buffer (name)
  (interactive "sNew scratch buffer's name (don't include asterisks): " name)
  (progn (switch-to-buffer-other-window (format "*%s*" name))
         (lisp-interaction-mode)))
```

Some people might think that automagically adding asterisks like that is annoying.  Others might prefer to use `switch-to-buffer` instead of `switch-to-buffer-other-window`.  But hopefully this is something you and other people can adapt and build on.